# Subtracting columns in a loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I've got a data frame like that:

```
df:
   A  B  C
1  1  2  3
2  2  2  4
3  2  2  3
```

I would like to subtract each column with the next smaler one (A-0, B-A, C-B). So my results should look like that:

```
df:
   A  B  C
1  1  1  1
2  2  0  2
3  2  0  1
```

I tried the following loop, but it didn't work.

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  j <- data[,i+1] - data[,i]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
df - cbind(0, df[-ncol(df)])

#   A B C
# 1 1 1 1
# 2 2 0 2
# 3 2 0 1
```

***Data***

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 2), B = c(2, 2, 2), C = c(3, 4, 3))
```

Comment: @bwi321 If my answer has solved your problem, please mark it as "accepted". Read [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/412699) for more details about accepting an answer.

Comment: I have to wait a few minutes until I'm able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

We can also remove the first and last column and do the subtraction

```
df[-1] <- df[-1]-df[-length(df)]
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 2), B = c(2, 2, 2), C = c(3, 4, 3))
```